# Split string containing math equations

Tags: ruby, string

I want to split the following string that contains equation:

```
sentence = "The integral of y^{n} is \frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1} when n \neq -1:"
```

The expected result is:

```
[y^{n}, \frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1}, n \neq -1:]
```

The problem is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUot0.jpg). [Mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) automatically concatenates the sentences removing spaces.

I was able to remove the strings using the following methods.

```
phrase = 'The integral of '
sentence.gsub(/#{phrase}/, '')
# => "y^{n} is \frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1} when n \neq -1:"

is = 'is'
sentence.gsub(/#{is}/, '')
# => y^{n}  \frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1} when n \neq -1:"

when_word = 'when'
sentence.gsub(/#{when_word}/, '')
# => "y^{n}  \frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1}  n \neq -1:"
```

I tried with `split`, but did not get the expected result.

```
sentence.split(', ')
# => ["y^{n}  \frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1}  n \neq -1:"]
```

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Is all your euqation going to be in the format like : The integral of *FRAGMENT* is *FRAGMENT* when *FRAGMENT*

Comment: Yes, that is why I want to split it, need to remove the sentences so i can just type that HTML. The problem is here - https://imgur.com/a/1WeYK

Comment: It is still unclear after I saw your link... you better put 3 set of examples and 3 set of expected output.. to assist you further

Comment: I added more explanation to the question. Mathjax concatenates the string unexpectedly. That's why i need to remove the string and just use Mathjax only on the equations. Then type the words in HTML.

Comment: You are telling Ruby to split the string at the commas, but there are no commas in the string, what do you expect to happen in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding of your question, this is what you want.

```
str = "The integral of y^{n} is \frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1} when n \neq -1:"
str.split(/\bThe integral of\b | \bis\b | \bwhen\b/)[1..-1]

#=> ["y^{n}", "\frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1}",  " n \neq -1:"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most straightforward.

```
string.match(/\AThe integral of (.*) is (.*) when (.*)\z/m).captures
#=> ["y^{n}", "\frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1}", "n \neq -1:"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the backslashes are part of the formula, they will need to be escaped with additional backslashes. (If you are reading the string from a file, or other source, rather than specifying it in source code, this should not be necessary.) Here is a script that does that and then does the parsing. It is not as elegant as Anurag's solution, but it does the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

s = "The integral of y^{n} is \\frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1} when n \\neq -1:"

s = s.split(/ of /).last
frag1, rest = s.split(/ is /)
frag2, frag3 = rest.split(/ when /)
puts %Q{Fragment 1: "#{frag1}"}
puts %Q{Fragment 2: "#{frag2}"}
puts %Q{Fragment 3: "#{frag3}"}

=begin
Outputs:

Fragment 1: "y^{n}"
Fragment 2: "\frac{y^{n + 1}}{n + 1}"
Fragment 3: "n \neq -1:"

=end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the sentence - string pops up dynamically from user input, how can i insert the extra backlash to the equation? The only thing constant in the sentence are the strings that I want to remove and then put back with plain HTML.

Comment: I think you won't need to do anything. The backslash characters would be included in the input string. The extra backslash (i.e. the escaping) is only needed when expressing the string literally in the source code.